# Creating Html Element from multidimensional Array

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

Not sure how will i able to explain this, but here we go

I have an array as below:

```
$arr = array(
    array('id' => 1,
        'content' => '<h1>This is a simple Content</h1>',
        'vars' => null,
        'path' => 'holders/row.php',
        'sub-page' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'content' => '<h1>Sample Body Here</h1>',
            'vars' => '{"title":"Sample Title Here"}',
            'path' => 'holders/box.php',
            'sub-page' => array(
                'id' => 3,
                'vars' => '{"title":"Sample Title NUmber 3 Here"}',
                'content' => '<h1>Again Sample Body Here</h1>',
                'path' => 'holders/box.php'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

What i am looking for is 
array should go to the deepest `sub-page` and `json_decode` the `vars` key and extract as variables and include the file.

Once this is done, the output is passed to the parent's content key and parse it again

*This is basically for creating dynamic content*

the `holders/row.php` contains:

```
<div class="row">
    <?= $content; ?>
</div>
```

and `holders/box.php` contains:

```
<div class="box lite">
    <div class="box-title">
        <h4><?= $title; ?></h4>

        <div class="tools">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        <?= $content; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the desired output is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="box lite">
        <div class="box-title">
            <h4>Sample Title Here</h4>

            <div class="tools">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <h1>Again Sample Body Here</h1>

            <div class="box lite">
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h4>Sample Title NUmber 3 Here</h4>

                    <div class="tools">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <h1>Again Sample Body Here</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### What have i tried so far

I am trying to loop around the array as below:

```
foreach ($arr as &$page) {
    if (isset($page[$keyToParse])) {
        $subMenu = $page[$keyToParse];
        unset($page[$keyToParse]);
        $page['content'] = $page['content'] . $this->parsePage($keyToParse, $subMenu);
        return $page['content'];
    } else {
        $params = strlen($page['vars']) > 0 ? json_decode($page['vars'], true) : [];
        $elementPath = $page['path'];
        $params = array_merge($params, array('content' => $page['content']));
        $page['content'] = callback(function () use ($params, $elementPath) {
            extract($params);
            include($elementPath);
        });

        return $page['content'];
    }
```

and the function callback is as:

```
function callback($userfunc)
{
    ob_start();
    $userfunc();
    $return = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $return;
}
```

Please help as i am stuck for a long time now

Comment: Blah, I really think you should invest in a templating framework out there..

Comment: You are really overcomplicating things. If you have to, write a class in combo with a master template and `sprintf` then output that.

Comment: @techouse, can you show a working example implicating your suggestion please

Comment: You should avoid using short PHP tags. They're not enabled on some (I think most) hosting servers. Additionally, they cause issues if you're working with XML and PHP in the same file. http://www.ehow.com/info_12178533_shouldnt-use-php-short-tags.html

Comment: As of PHP 5.4 the short echo tag is correctly parsed regardless of the short open tag directive. IMHO using the short echo syntax in templates results in much easier to read code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you should have to do is something like this.

```
function renderNode($node){
        ob_start();
        if (isset($node["sub-page"]) && $node["sub-page"]){
                $node["content"] = renderNode($node["sub-page"]);
        }
        extract($node);
        include ($node["path"]);
        return ob_get_clean();
}
```

and then invoke it like:

```
echo renderNode($arr[0]);
```

Comment: Wow! didnt knew it could be this simple! Silly me of not thinking this before. Thanks Orangepill

Comment: I am not able to award you your earned bounty. Will be able to do it in the next 21 hours. Will try to award it to you tomorrow. Thanks for your help!